# Google Big Query Import Issue

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I have a problem during importing a CSV into Big QUery. Even though, the colum is defined as 'string' some of the numbers still appear in date format. I have no further idea what can I change. What I have tried so far:

- with CONAT in Excel I made the following - (space)number and placed into own value. I read somewhere, that this can fix the auto date defining function but nothing happened
- tried in Big Query the CAST. Nothing changed.

It's even more frustrating that only 1 colum results this issue, the rest of 3 are completely fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your data is in excel and you exported a csv file? Could it be that in excel the values are already formated as date.

Comment: It is saved as CSV (previosuly cleaned and formatted in Excel)

Comment: You need to clean the data in Excel. Excel interpretes 3.3 sometimes as 3th of March and so on.